# Convert DXT1 .asset to iPhone

Tags: compression, unity-game-engine

While building my project i get this error:

> DXT1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to iPhone

The file is a ".asset" used in shaders material.

Is there any way to convert it to iPhone supported format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert you need export the asset file again, using the iPhone as platform. Switching the platform in Unity after generating the asset won't do it since, as you can see, Unity don't reconvert it.

So get the Unity project that created this asset and re export it using iPhone as the target platform.